# File share not able to be seen except by creator

Tags: file-sharing

I have a Samba file share that I can see from a windows machine.  The problem is when I create files or folders, only the creator machine can see them.  I can create Windows files but cannot see them in Ubuntu.  I can create files on Ubuntu but cannot see them in Windows.  I am thinking it is some permissions in the smb.conf file but am having issues figuring it out.

My main goal is to use this as a media server so the windows boxes, tv and dvd players should be able to connect and see the files without passwords.  Also I'd like to upload content from any machine and have it accessible to any machine on the network.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with your smb.conf file. You are going to want to have your media stanza look something like this:

```
[media]
   comment = Shared Media Files
   path = /path/to/media
   public = yes
   writable = yes
   create mask = 0666
   directory mask = 0777
   guest ok = yes
   force user = bob
   force group = bob
```

That will do what you want. Everyone will have read/write access to everything. change the user/group to the user/group of the admin on your Samba box.